# what does sqlstate[42703] mean on heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku

I have created a laravel app and everything is working as it should on my localhost. I am using XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin to test the application locally and when I uploaded it to Heroku and configured the database and run the "heroku run php artisan migrate" without errors so far.

My application is a simple form where the user registers information and it is stored in the database. the database consists of some tables. here is the migration for the users table

```
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('username')->uniqe();
        $table->string('ssn');
        $table->string('lastfour');
        $table->unique(array('ssn','lastfour'));
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('role')->default('Applicant');
        $table  ->foreign('role')
                ->references('name')
                ->on('role');
        $table->date('applicationDate');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('application_result')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and the competence_profile migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('competence_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('competence_profile_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('person_id');
        $table  ->foreign('person_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

        $table->String('competence');
        $table  ->foreign('competence')
                ->references('name')
                ->on('competence');
        $table->integer('years_of_experience');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

however, I got the error when I submit the form to the database only on Heroku. as mentioned it works fine locally and I can see the data stored in phpmyadmin. here is the error exception is shown from Heroku.

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...t", "created_at") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning
>   "id" ^ (SQL: insert into "competence_profile" ("person_id",
>   "competence", "years_of_experience", "updated_at", "created_at")
>   values (4, Designer, 6, 2019-02-22 11:36:29, 2019-02-22 11:36:29)
>   returning "id").

I would appreciate any explanation or help about this error. it is basically not finding the column even though it is defined in the migration.

Comment: have you found that the database structure on heroku is similar to your localhost ?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42703]` means the column was undefined. Helpfully it comes with a plain text description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution to the SQLState[42703] which you get from heroku. When you have a table in the database, heroku assumes that the primary key for that table is called 'id'. If you have a primary key that is called other than that (in this case the primary key is called competence_profile_id) you need to add a variable in the model with the value of the primary key that you have. I have named the variable in my competence_profile model as follows $primaryKey = 'competence_profile_id'; and that fixed the problem